# Problema com event keyup

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Neste script, estou pegando uma data de início de um `datepicker`, e a ela estou somando a semana que o cara digitar com mais 5 dias. O problema é que ele só aplica essa regra na primeira data que seleciono. Se eu seleciono outra data de início, ele retorna a mesma data da primeira selecionada. Aparentemente ele grava a primeira data e fica nisso.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#semanas").keyup(function( event ){
        var date = $('#data-inicio').val();
        var semanas = ($(this).val());
        var diaSeg = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
        var total = (diaSeg * 7) * semanas + 432000000;
        total = total / diaSeg;
        date = date.split("/").reverse().join("-");
        date = new Date(date);
        var dia = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDay() + total);
        $("#data-retorno").datepicker('setDate', new Date(dia));
    });
});
```